# Numpy sort rows in a 4d array and sum the same values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks like this

```
4.9 6.14923e-01 -4.7827e-01 -6.8341e+00
1.2 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -7.9249e+00
3.4 -4.7827e-01 -6.1492e-01 -6.8341e+00
6.8 -4.7827e-01 -4.7827e-01 -7.4221e+00
5.2 6.14923e-01 -4.7827e-01 -6.8341e+00
1.4 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -7.9249e+00
2.6 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
2.8 -4.7827e-01 -6.1492e-01 -6.8341e+00
5.6 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
4.1 -4.7827e-01 -4.7827e-01 -7.4221e+00
2.2 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
```

The three last columns are coordinates (x, y, z).

So I basically want to sum for each repeat value ox x, y and z the value in the first column.

The output after sorting is like this:

```
2.8 -4.7827e-01 -6.1492e-01 -6.8341e+00
3.4 -4.7827e-01 -6.1492e-01 -6.8341e+00
6.8 -4.7827e-01 -4.7827e-01 -7.4221e+00
4.1 -4.7827e-01 -4.7827e-01 -7.4221e+00
1.2 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -7.9249e+00
1.4 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -7.9249e+00
2.6 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
5.6 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
2.2 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
5.2 6.14923e-01 -4.7827e-01 -6.8341e+00
4.9 6.14923e-01 -4.7827e-01 -6.8341e+00
```

and after summing the first column for each unique value

```
6.2  -4.7827e-01 -6.1492e-01 -6.8341e+00
10.9 -4.7827e-01 -4.7827e-01 -7.4221e+00
2.6  -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -7.9249e+00
10.4 -4.7827e-01 -3.4162e-01 -6.9302e+00
10.1 6.14923e-01 -4.7827e-01 -6.8341e+00
```

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a `groupby`-like behavior using a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.  However, this requires some work, because sparse won't deal well with the three columns you want to groupby.

However, we can use `np.unique` to return the unique values, as well as the inverse, so that we can turn three columns into a `1D` array, while still saving multiple columns to re-add at the end:

---

```
from scipy import sparse

v, bins = np.unique(a[:, 1:], axis=0, return_inverse=True)
vals = a[:, 0]

out = sparse.csr_matrix(
    (vals, bins, np.arange(vals.shape[0]+1)), (vals.shape[0], bins.max()+1)
).sum(0).A1

np.column_stack((out, v))
```

```
array([[ 6.2     , -0.47827 , -0.61492 , -6.8341  ],
       [10.9     , -0.47827 , -0.47827 , -7.4221  ],
       [ 2.6     , -0.47827 , -0.34162 , -7.9249  ],
       [10.4     , -0.47827 , -0.34162 , -6.9302  ],
       [10.1     ,  0.614923, -0.47827 , -6.8341  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of issue is very easily solved with `pandas`, and more code-intensive if you want a pure python or `numpy` solution. I would suggest:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['A','X','Y','Z'])

new_df = df.groupby(['X','Y','Z'],as_index=False).sum()

new_arr = new_df[['A','X','Y','Z']].values

>>> new_arr
array([[ 6.2     , -0.47827 , -0.61492 , -6.8341  ],
       [10.9     , -0.47827 , -0.47827 , -7.4221  ],
       [ 2.6     , -0.47827 , -0.34162 , -7.9249  ],
       [10.4     , -0.47827 , -0.34162 , -6.9302  ],
       [10.1     ,  0.614923, -0.47827 , -6.8341  ]])

# All in one line, without saving intermediate steps to memory:

# new_arr pd.DataFrame(arr).groupby([1,2,3],as_index=False).sum()[[0,1,2,3]].values
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a=[[4.9, 6.14923e-01, -4.7827e-01, -6.8341e+00],
[1.2, -4.7827e-01, -3.4162e-01 ,-7.9249e+00],
[3.4, -4.7827e-01, -6.1492e-01, -6.8341e+00],
[6.8, -4.7827e-01, -4.7827e-01, -7.4221e+00],
[5.2, 6.14923e-01, -4.7827e-01, -6.8341e+00],
[1.4, -4.7827e-01, -3.4162e-01, -7.9249e+00],
[2.6, -4.7827e-01, -3.4162e-01, -6.9302e+00],
[2.8, -4.7827e-01, -6.1492e-01, -6.8341e+00],
[5.6, -4.7827e-01, -3.4162e-01, -6.9302e+00],
[4.1, -4.7827e-01, -4.7827e-01, -7.4221e+00],
[2.2, -4.7827e-01, -3.4162e-01, -6.9302e+00]]
a=np.array(a)
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df['sum']=df.groupby([1,2,3])[0].transform('sum')
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[1,2,3])[[1,2,3,'sum']]
```